# Why use short data type for storing RGB values?

Tags: java, integer, int, short

I am doing a project from Berkeley 61B MOOC. In this, I have to create an array to represent the pixels of the image and the RGB values for each. I am using a 3D array for the same:

```
image=new int[width][height][3];
```

However, I came upon this statement from the project's description:

> Each pixel has three numbers in the range 0...255 representing the
>   red, green, and blue intensities of the pixel.  These three bytes are
>   known as the RGB values of the image.  A pixel in which all three
>   values are zero is pure black, and a pixel in which all three values
>   are 255 is bright white.  Although Java has a "byte" integer type, its
>   range is -128...127, so we will usually use Java's "short" type for
>   methods that take RGB parameters or return RGB values.

As far as I know, a int type is sufficient for containing values from 0-255.
Please help me understand, in plain English, the reason suggesting the use of short data type.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: I would suggest to use 1 int for the 3 values instead (the 3 lower bytes).

Answer (score -1):

int is 32 bit, short is 16 and byte is 8. You don't need 32 bits for [0, 255] range, but byte's range [-128, 127] is not good for representing RGB, so short is what you got.

Comment: Byte is 8 bits, it has all the range needed. It's up to you whether you decide to represent it as an unsigned or signed value, it doesn't affect the working of the program.